# Implementing Reset Password and Email Changes in Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

I'm currently working on a python-based app engine website and am looking to add google identity toolkit functionality but am getting stuck on the implementation of password resets and changes to email address..

Have been able to get the python quickstart example (https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/python) working properly but even using this, I haven't been able to properly set up the password reset and email change components

I've been going through the google groups for this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-identity-toolkit but can't seem to be able to find detailed steps or sample code based off python

Would anybody have any ideas or can point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've been able to get this to work by:

1. creating a gitkit instance using the gitkit server config json
2. calling the GetOobResult function, which sends back a dict containing the reset link, among other information (This is the crux)
3. finally, to get the user notification to work properly you'll need to return a json dump with {'success' : true}

Here are the key lines of code I used -- should note that this doesn't include the email sending portion with the password reset link, which you have to implement separate from gitkit..

```
server_config_json = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gitkit-server-config.json')
gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient.FromConfigFile(server_config_json)
output = gitkit_instance.GetOobResult(self.request.POST,self.request.remote_addr)

if output:
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps({'success': True} ))
```